# dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 7

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, virtual-machine

I've used GRUB to dual boot before but I find that in general I always boot into Ubuntu unless I'm going to play a game that's not Linux supported.

Two main questions here

1. Can I set up the boot loader to always boot Linux unless I "opt-out"? Either by setting a flag on disc when I restart, or having to press an f key at a specific time.
2. Would I see a noticible difference in gameplay performance if I run windows off of a VM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I set up the boot loader to always boot Linux unless I "opt-out"? Either by setting a flag on disc when I restart, or having to press an f key at a specific time.

Should be very easy to do by editing `/boot/grub.cfg file`.

You can read the [GRUB tutorial](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/grub-2.html) to find out how.

> Would I see a noticeable difference in gameplay performance if I run windows off of a VM?

It does affect the gameplay because you are sharing the hardware resources by two operating systems. It is possible to configure your graphics card to work with your VM. Read [here](http://www.ehow.com/how_6049676_configure-virtual-machine-vmware-player.html).

Answer (score 1):

You just edit boot/grub/grub.cfg and there is a line named set default="0" set it into 1 if your windows installation is placed second in your boot menu otherwise open and comment other options in grub.cfg and change the default value problem will be solved . If you are playing game using VM it is not capable of processing thats much of graphics as windows ...